# Exp channel give category condition

Tags: channel

I want to set a condition for category in exp channel tag which should result in a condition:
"where category = 3 and category=2"
How can I give this condition in exp?
 "category=3&2 " and category="3|2"  not getting the correct results,they return the same query
  If anyone knows, please help.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="your_channel" category_group="your_cat_group" category="2&3" dynamic="no"}
```

My understanding of it is as follows:

"2&3" - This returns all entries which are tagged as belonging to 2 AND 3.

"2|3" - This returns all entries which are tagged either 2 or 3.

So, the first will only return entries that have both categories set and the latter will get all categories where both are set OR only one of them.